# text-align:center doesn't work vertically in CSS, how can I get around this?

Tags: html, css

I'm working with a div that's only holding text. It's using absolute positioning to center itself on top of an image div that is using relative positioning . I can center the div horizontally in CSS if I use

`div {
text-align:center;
width:100%;
}`

But when I try to center it vertically using

`div {
text-align:center;
height:100%;
}`

it doesn't vertically center. I'm guessing this is because text-align:center only specifies horizontally.. How could I get around this? I've seen a couple solutions that would work if the outer div is a fixed size, but the outer div is not a fixed size. It's fluid so I need this to work fluidly as well. I've tried using top:50% but I want it perfectly centered... I'm pretty inexperienced so go easy on me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you guessed, you are right, `text-align: center;` is used to align the text/element horizontally only and not vertically... so if you are talking about aligning the single line text vertically than you need to use `line-height`, which will be equal to the container `height`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ktcg5/)

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center; /* Forgot this in the demo */
}
```

Where as if you are looking to vertical align entire element, than you can use either `position: absolute;` which I won't suggest you, instead use `display: table-cell;` nested inside `display: table;` parent

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/ktcg5/1/)

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    display: table;
}

span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Hmm I couldn't get either method to work... Second one really looks promising but for both it would center it inside of the set dimensions( height:100px; width:100px; } but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require dimensions since this div is fluid and will increase/decrease depending on viewport. I'm mostly working with percentages because of this

Comment: @fuccboi you can use `%` with the second method as well

Comment: I set both height and width to 50% and it worked beautifully. Thank you Mr. Alien, problem solved

Comment: @fuccboi not only `span`, even a `div` can work the same way, it's just a table cell, which is aligned *vertically* to `middle` :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
div {  position:absolute; top:50%; }
```

and go through

http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html

Comment: This is actually bad, what if the content grows? It won't be vertically centered

Comment: Read my answer for a better solution

Comment: Mr. Alien is correct, top:50% will start the text at 50%, and instances where the div is small this is very noticeable. I'm looking for a solution that will start the text at the vertical center line of the text.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one. Make the code as

```
div { text-align:center; line-height:100%; }
```

Comment: this is not the answer of the question

Comment: then wats ur answer...?

Comment: Is this align the text vertically center??

Comment: Try to detail your answer, this solution will only work with a single line of text.