# Horizontal center variable width div within div, mouse events beside must pass through?

Tags: html, css

How can I horizontally center a variable-width div within another div with a specific offset from the top (or vertically centered as well)? An extra condition is that only the visible part of the div must intercept mouse events -- this limits some of the options.

```
+--------------+
|  outer div   +
|   <innner>   +
+--------------+
```

`inner` contains clickable elements and must be at the top of the stacking order. The `outer div` is clickable as well, thus the area around `inner` must pass mouse events to the underlying div. `inner` is a variable width. `inner` must have some offset from the top of `outer`.

I know there are a lot of related centering questions, but the mouse events aspect here makes this different.

Comment: Just answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20988457/1542290

Comment: @Mr.Alien that doesn't solve the mouse issue. The table blocks all mouse events from reaching the underlying elements.

Comment: can you show us some code?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have an outer div with the class outer, and inside it there's another div having class="inner".
The centering can be achieved by css:

```
.outer {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    line-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
}

.inner {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

I added click events to the outer div, and for the button inside the inner div. The button click will propagate to the outer div by default.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/er144/bh3V9/